# Can we show our HDFS data, or Map Reduce output into HTML form or JSP page?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to show our HDFS data, or Map Reduce output into HTML form or JSP page? 
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of webservices and J2EE project, using Hadoop filesystem api  ( refer [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) ) to cat hdfs files you could show the results in webpages.

**But , Keep in mind** the size of data you are handling , huge data (TBs ans PBs ) will also affect your web apps memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to showcase your data, and fire commands without dropping to the shell every time. In the case, try out **HUE** ([website](http://gethue.com/)). HDFS, hive, pig, impala, sqoop : they've got everything covered. You can give commands through a web interface and get results on the browser, which are downloadable as well.

Let me know if this works.